# Italic Acronyms with normal Subscripts

Tags: acronyms, subscripts, italic

I use the `acronym` package for my acronyms. Is there a way to make the acronyms non italic in the Acronym List itself but use them in an italic form in the text? Most of the time it works with `\textit{\acs{XY}}` but when I have a subscript in the acronym I don't want the subscript to be italic. 
For example in the code below I want to link Mint to the acronym list, "Min" should be italic and the subcript "t" non italic. How can I do that?

```
  \documentclass[oneside, english, 12pt]{book}
  \usepackage{acronym}
  \begin{document}

  \begin{acronym}
  \acro{Mint} [Min\textsubscript{t}]{Position of Minimum}
  \end{acronym}

   'Min' should be italic and the subscript 't' nonitalic.
    And the whole word linked to the acronym list \textit{\acs{Mint}}


  \end{document}
```

Comment: And you want it to be bold in the first list of acronyms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you seek?  If so, I would note it was accomplished by explicitly enclosing the subscript text in a `\textup{}`.

```
  \documentclass[oneside, english, 12pt]{book}
  \usepackage{acronym}
  \begin{document}

  \begin{acronym}
  \acro{Mint} [Min\textsubscript{\textup{t}}]{Position of Minimum}
  \end{acronym}

   'Min' should be italic and the subscript 't' nonitalic.
    And the whole word linked to the acronym list \textit{\acs{Mint}}


  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @christian Great!  Glad to assist.  I see you have asked several questions without "accepting" any answers.  If an answer to your own (or any other) question is *useful*, you can click the up-arrow to the left of the answer to "upvote" the answer.  To your own questions, if there is one answer that fully answers your need and is superior to all the others, you can click the check mark to the left of the question to "accept" it.  That tells other readers what it was that you found best helped your need.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wasn't really aware of that feature, but catch up on that in a minute. Thanks again for the help!